# Where function is defined when alias of same name exists

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a function

```
sql() { ... }
```

and an alias of same name

```
alias sql="noglob sql"
```

I know I can use `type somefunction` to find the definition of a function, but in this case it doesn't work. The only way I found is to unalias the alias, which is not very practical.

```
❯ type sql

sql is an alias for noglob sql

❯ unalias sql ; type sql

sql is a shell function from /home/sparc/bin/zsh_libs/zsh_sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
❯ echo $functions_source[sql] 
/home/sparc/bin/zsh_libs/zsh_sql
```

This won't work on all zsh versions.
Check if it exists before using it with:

```
(($+functions_source)) && echo works
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply escape part of the command name:

```
% \sql
```

Alias expansion happens *before* quote removal, so the `\` prevents a match against an alias from succeeding. A function name lookup happens *after* quote removal.

```
% foo () { echo function ;}
% alias foo='echo alias'
% foo
alias
% \foo
function
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# only check function definition by option `-f`
type -f sql
```

> -f
>   Causes  the contents of a **shell function** to be displayed,
>   which would otherwise not happen unless the -c flag  were
>   used.

The solution is ZSH exclusive. You may need to use another option on other shells.

Comment: Doen't  work.
`❯ type -f sql`
gives:
`sql is an alias for noglob sql`